# "invalid operator grep"

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

```
Echo enter file name
Read file
Echo enter pattren
Read pattren
If [ grep $pattern $file ]
Then
Echo pattern found
Else 
Echo not found
Fi
```

When I run this, I'm getting an error like `invalid operator grep`

Comment: linux is very case sensitive ... Echo is not the correct spelling which is echo ... typically  commands are  lowecase

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you don't want to check that there is such a string as `grep $pattern $file` but whether there is any output from the command, so something like `[[ $(grep foo bar) ]]` would work. Or as @steeldriver pointed out, you can simply check the exit status of `grep`:

```
echo "enter file name: "
read file
echo "enter pattern: "
read pattern
if grep -q "$pattern" "$file"; then 
   echo "yeah, got it"
   else echo "nope, sorry, got nothing"
fi
```

Obviously, fix the caps. `Echo` is not a command.

Comment: Side note: in `bash` one can get rid of `echo` and use `read` alone like: `read -p "Enter pattern: " pattern`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy indeed, good point! Less ambiguous too

Answer (score 0):

The `test` command ( also known as `[` ) has specific operators, the list of which you can find in `man test` manual. Thus, `[ grep $pattern $file ]` is incorrect, since you're giving `[` 3 arguments that it doesn't recognize.

What you likely want to do is what Zanna showed - use `grep`  within if statement to evaluate exit status only. Alternatively, you can store output of `grep` to variable and check if that variable is non-empty something along these lines:

```
output=$(grep "$pattern" "$file" 2> /dev/null)    
if [ -n "$output" ];
then
    echo "Got something"
else
    echo "Nothing"
fi
```

More frequently, you'll see something like this done in practice:

```
if [ "x$output" != "x" ]
then
    echo "Got something"
else
    echo "Nothing"
fi
```